# xorg crash and returns to the login screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg

On Ubuntu 15.04 When using mostly any gnome application after few seconds everything close at I am back to the login prompt. I tried with the nouveau and the Nvidia driver but no change. Chrome is running fine, Krusader to and Terminal to. lspci gives me:

```
 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Device 0925
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
Memory at d2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at d3000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

I found few related info in dmesg:

```
    nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   19.519205] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   19.522175] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
```

or `NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
[   19.756546] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as: 
NVRM: nouveau, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv 
NVRM: was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
[   19.756549] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
NVRM: again.
[   19.756551] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
[   19.756553] [drm] Module unloaded
[   19.756737] NVRM: NVIDIA init module failed!`

It was working before until some update. I look around in many forums but I can't find anything helpful, so any advice welcome
Thanks!